# load the whole table into multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

i have one table for example col A col B col C col D

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // code here to echo all data you need 
    // for example echo $result['colA'], $result['colB'] 
}
```

what i need is the following :

```
while($this->result = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->query))   
 { 
    $i = 1; 
    foreach ($this->result as $k => $v) 
    {   
        $this->newarray = array ($i => ($this->result[$k]=>$this->result[$v], $this->result[$k]=>$this->result[$v], $this->result[$k]=>$this->result[$v], ....);
    }   
 $i++; 
 }
```

so the final array i can got like this :

```
$newarray = array( "first_row" =>   
   ("$result[colA]" => "$result[value]",
    "$result[colB]" => "$result[value]", 
    "$result[colC]" => "$result[value]");
```

so i can use return the whole array all at once and i can use it:

```
echo $newarray[0]['colA'];  
echo $newarray[3]['colA'];
```

i hope i explained my question in a good way. thank you in advance

Comment: i don't know why u deleted it .. it's correct . thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO to do your queries you can use the result set meta-data to get the column information. Then loop over this to create your array(s).

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php